# Train a model in Keras with non-differentiable layer

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, quantization

How can I train a deep neural net in Kera(Tensorflow) with a Quantization layer in middle? i.e. I want to make the representation in a particular layer of the network be quantized (using Vector quantization) and then passed to the next layer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Lambda Layer](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda).

```
def quantize(x):
    # Your vector quantization code

model.add(Lambda(quantize))
```